# How do we create a Cloudant DB connection from Notebook and stash data in IBM Bluemix?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, jupyter-notebook, cloudant

Currently I am trying to stash data into Cloudant DB from a notebook using Python's Pixiedust package. After establishing a connection it gives me this error when trying to insert data into the database.

```
nPy4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o172.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 38.0 failed 10 times, most recent failure: '
Lost task 3.9 in stage 38.0 (TID 1811, yp-spark-dal09-env5-0046): spray.http.IllegalUriException: The path of an URI without authority must not begin with "//"
```

Please tell me how I can stash data into Cloudant DB from a notebook?
[check error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmLEK.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide more details on the actual code, not just the error message?

Comment: i have dataframe df which contain on my data when i display using pixiedust display function .table created successfully but when i try to stash to cloudent it give me error.I also added image in question.pleas check that also.

Comment: This was a bug in PixieDust and has been addressed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015836/how-we-stash-data-to-cloudant-db-in-ibm-bluemix/40031314#40031314