# How we stash Data to Cloudant DB in IBM Bluemix?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, cloudant, pixiedust

Currently I am trying to stash data into Cloudant DB from a notebook using Python's Pixiedust package. After establishing a connection it gives me this error when trying to insert data into the database.

```
nPy4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o172.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 38.0 failed 10 times, most recent failure: '
Lost task 3.9 in stage 38.0 (TID 1811, yp-spark-dal09-env5-0046): spray.http.IllegalUriException: The path of an URI without authority must not begin with "//"
```

Please tell me how I can stash data into Cloudant DB from a notebook?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. This is a known issue with Pixiedust that we are working on. We should have a fix very soon. I will comment here when it is released.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been addressed and a new version of PixieDust has been uploaded to PyPI. You can download the latest version in your notebook by issuing the following command:

`!pip install --user --upgrade --no-deps pixiedust`

Restart your kernel after the upgrade is complete.

You can verify your PixieDust version (this was fixed in version 0.40) by running the following command:

`!pip show pixiedust`

The output should look similar to the following:

```
---
Metadata-Version: 1.0
Name: pixiedust
Version: 0.40
Summary: Misc helpers for Spark Python Notebook
Home-page: https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/pixiedust
Author: David Taieb
Author-email: david_taieb@us.ibm.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /gpfs/global_fs01/sym_shared/YPProdSpark/user/sc7c-6877c2673165c0-9db077469d48/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: maven-artifact, mpld3
Classifiers:
```

Comment: markwatsonatx thanks for solving this issue.its now working fine. :)